# Centralizar <div>

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de saber o motivo de minha `<div>` não estar centralizada no meio da página, ela esta na extrema direita como no exemplo que criei abaixo:

```css
div#pagina-principal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagina-fundo">
  <div id="fundo">
    <img src="_imagens/background.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="pagina-principal">
  <header id="cabecalho">

    <nav id="navegacao">
      <ul>
        <a href="principal.html"><img src="_imagens/simbolo.webp" alt=""></a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </header>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa página acredito que pode ser esse seu problema:
A propriedade left somada a propriedade position somada a propriedade margin do elemento, é o que está causando o erro de posicionamento. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua `div` é filha direta do `body`, e está com `position: absolute`, então quando vc coloca `left: 50%` nessa `div` quer dizer que a `div` vai alinhar a partir de `50% do body`, e não centralizado no `body` conforme imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma das formas de centralizar como `position: absolute`, a que eu indico nesse caso em particular é colocar `left/right` com `0` e `margin: auto`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Execute o código em tela cheia!**

```css
div#pagina-principal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagina-fundo">
  <div id="fundo">
    <img src="_imagens/background.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="pagina-principal">
  <header id="cabecalho">

    <nav id="navegacao">
      <ul>
        <a href="principal.html"><img src="_imagens/simbolo.webp" alt=""></a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </header>
</div>
```